# Including font using CSS to support IE7 (IE6 dont care)

Tags: css

The following CSS works for me to make FontAwesome visible in all browsers, except it doesn't work for IE7. Struggling to work out how to fix it.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('fontawesome-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Im not using any advanced CSS like the `:before` selector, Even this doesn't work:

```
<span style="font-family:FontAwesome;"></span>
```

Comment: Please Visit this link U will get answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669791/font-awesome-and-ie7-issues/19669822#19669822

Answer (score 0):

The FontAwesome download on the GitHub site has a specific IE7 stylesheet with worked for me.

Comment: That only works if you want to use font-awesome. Apparently IE7 already has support for embedding fonts. I just need to work out how.