# Font awesome and ie7 issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'm using bootstrap 3 and have to support ie7. Ideally I would like to use font for icons. They work great in all other browsers except ie7 :(

The icons appear fine using ie on the font awesome website - I have had a look at what's different and I cant see anything out of th ordinary. I've followed the instructions and added the css in order etc...

I'm not using less. Here is a link to my test site https://googledrive.com/host/0B8UWGEiox1HOZnV6ZTA3bzNvMTA/testsite.html

The test site show font awesome using ie tester however that isnt 100% accurate. I am using true ie7 to test on and the font is simply squares.

Please can anybody see what's going on here as I'm  at an end with it!

```
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link href="css/main-ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
```

Comment: Your `.eot` file is being served with the wrong MIME type, which might be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font Awesome version 4.0.1 does not support IE7, see the bottom of their getting started page: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Version 3.2.1 has support, see their IE7 section at the bottom of their 3.2.1 getting page 
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/get-started/

There is an app called Icomoon that can create custom icon fonts, and can include icons from Font Awesome.  Their old version of the application generates a Javascript file for IE7 that will allow the icon fonts to be used, the old version of the app is here http://icomoon.io/app-old/

Comment: I am using 3.2.1 and read those instructions so should work. Thanks I will give that app a look if nobody can see why this is failing.

Comment: I cant look at your google drive site where I am right now.  I always use Icomoon for my projects, and their IE7 javascript file works.  Also, you can pick and choose what icons you want from font awesome so you don't need to load every one if you only need a couple. And make sure you use the "Old" icomoon app, I tried the new one and didn't see that IE7 JS file being generated.

Comment: The new version of IcoMoon also generates this IE7 js file if you check the "Support IE7" checkbox in the preferences panel.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the charset is assumed wrongly. Try including `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

If your icons **are not** intented to change at runtime, you can use the following CSS to add support for IE6 and IE7 for whatever icons you need :

```
.icon-glass {
  *zoom: expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xf000;');
}
```

If your icons **are** intended to change at runtime, you could do something like this instead :

```
.icon-glass {
  *top: expression(0, this.innerHTML = '&#xf000;');
}
```

Unfortunately, this second approach is extremely slow. While it is likely to work in IE6 with a significant reduction of your performance, IE7 is likely to crash if you have too many icons on your page. **So I wouldn't recommend this second technique unless you use only very few icons and you can afford the performance reduction.**